# Letter count from paragraph

Tags: javascript

So I transform paragraph into a string and try to count letters but...

HTML:

```
<p id="text">example text a</p>
<p id="example"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function alert(){
  var str = document.getElementById('text').outerHTML;
var counta = str.match(/a/g).length;
var countd = str.match(/d/g).length;
var county = str.match(/y/g).length;
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML= counta+ " " +countd+ " " + county;
}
```

I need to count every letter in a paragraph, but I have an issue. Like in the example below I would like to check counting for the letter "a", "d", "y". In my example, I don't have "y" letter and "d".
So why I have an output like 2 1 1?? Where I make a mistake??!!

Comment: You do know that this function overwrites the built-in `alert` function?

Comment: did you mean to use `innerHTML`, not `outerHTML`? You're searching the contents of the HTML tags and attributes with `outerHTML`.

Comment: Also note that `str.match()` can return null, which means that calling its length property will trigger an error.

Comment: innerHTML not working.. on that case outerHTML give a expected output when we count letters that exist in paragraph...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML), which includes the tag information (`<p id="text">`). That's why you have a d (in `id`).

Use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to get the content between the tags. You may even want to use [innerText](https://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext) so it ignores tags inside, I modified your example to contain a `<span>` to illustrate the point.

```js
function getCount(matchResult) {
  return matchResult ? matchResult.length : 0;
}

var innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
   
var counta = getCount(innerHTML.match(/a/g));
var countd = getCount(innerHTML.match(/d/g));
var county = getCount(innerHTML.match(/y/g));

document.getElementById("exampleInnerHTML").innerHTML = counta + " " + countd + " " + county;

var innerText = document.getElementById('text').innerText;

counta = getCount(innerText.match(/a/g));
countd = getCount(innerText.match(/d/g));
county = getCount(innerText.match(/y/g));

document.getElementById("exampleInnerText").innerHTML = counta + " " + countd + " " + county;
```

```html
<p id="text">example text <span>a</span></p>
<h2>Using innerHTML</h2>
<p id="exampleInnerHTML"></p>
<h2>Using innerText</h2>
<p id="exampleInnerText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 2 1 1 because you are using `outerHTML`.
`outerHTML` will give you the entire tag and its contents, in this case `<p id="text">example text a</p>` so you probably want to use `innerHTML` instead to only make the matching on the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`.
Moreover, you should rename your function, because you are overwriting the JS `alert` function.

But the issue you are getting here is that `.match` returns `null` if no match if found. So you need to set a default value to your count variables.

Try something like this :

```
function count(){
  var str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  var matcha = str.match(/a/g);
  var matchd = str.match(/d/g);
  var matchy = str.match(/y/g);
  var counta = matcha ? matcha.length : 0;
  var countd = matchd ? matchd.length : 0;
  var county = matchy ? matchy.length : 0;
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML= counta+ " " +countd+ " " + county;
}
```

Comment: Actually only one other answer gave a fix for the null issue, and I was actually writing and testing my script while the answer was published :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only grabbing the text content of the element using .textContent or a similar JS library method (.outerHTML was pulling in your html tags and attributes). That should do the trick.

Using .innerHTML could be problematic, as that method will, like outerHTML, return any embedded HTML tags and attributes. For example, I added a span surrounding your text. Using .innerHTML on the element with the id of "text" would return the span tags along with the text. Using .textContent will return only the content of the text node.

```js
function alert(){
  var str = document.getElementById("text").textContent;
  console.log(str); 
  
  var counta = str.match(/a/g).length;
  var countb = str.match(/b/g).length;
  
  console.log(str.match(/a/g));
  console.log(str.match(/b/g));
  
  console.log(counta);
  console.log(countb);
  
  var newStr = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  console.log(newStr);
}

alert();
```

```html
<p id="text"><span>an example text for the letters a and b</span></p>
<p id="example"></p>
```